# React: Multiple pages with client-side rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm making a React website with exactly two pages. Both pages contain exclusively dynamic content and making them work with Gatsby was the nightmare of my past days because most of the state necessary to generate the site is stored on the client. This is why I want to go back to pure client-side rendering.

I used to use `create-react-app` (this was great but then came the second page) but that is for SPAs and `react-router` doesn't work for me because I publish via GH pages. (I store a lot of current page info in the URL hash, so hash routing isn't something I want to deal with.)

What frameworks can I use that will generate me 2 `.html` pages?

Ideally, it would work like Gatsby in that it has a `pages` folder used to generate the blank `.html` pages ready for client-side rendering.

---

Notes: I'm not interested in React Native. I have a simple website build on React, not an app.

Comment: have you looked into `NextJS`?

Comment: I have. It can do SSR and even static site generation but not pure client-side rendering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I solved it.

You can use Gatsby with a little trick.

The trick is inspired by [this](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/using-client-side-only-packages/#workaround-4-use-reactlazy-and-suspense-on-client-side-only). I made a little function that conditionally renders a given component only on the client.

```
import React from "react";

export default function clientOnly(supplier: () => JSX.Element): JSX.Element {
    const isSSR = typeof window === "undefined";
    if (isSSR) {
        return <></>;
    } else {
        return supplier();
    }
}
```

The function is used like this:

```
import React from "react";
import clientOnly from "../client-only";
import ClientSideComponent from "../client-side-component";
import OtherStuff from "../other-stuff";

export default function HomePage(): JSX.Element {
    return (
        <>
            {clientOnly(() => (
                <ClientSideComponent />
            ))}
            <OtherStuff/>
        </>
    );
}
```

The main advantage of this approach is that client-side components are statically imported, so Gatsby can bundle them together with the rest.

The main disadvantage is that the static usage of browser variables (e.g. `window`, `location`, ...) is **impossible**. You can use them inside functions that are only executed on the browser but variables outside of functions won't work. 
It's possible to work around this by using either lazy initialization (e.g. using a class static `get` property) or a guard (e.g. `var foo = typeof window === "undefined" ? undefined : location.host;`).

In my case, I only had one static variable that used `window` and this was easily solved using a guard.

I hope this helps anyone with a similar issue.